# OpenCV HOGDescriptor returning wrong result in static image

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am trying to detect the presence of human in a static image using OpenCV HOGDescriptor in Android.

Here is the Android java code, I couldn't find an example in Android online, I tried to port the example in C++ in peopledetect.cpp to it.

```
mHOGDescriptor = new HOGDescriptor();
mHOGDescriptor.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor.getDefaultPeopleDetector());
Mat img = Highgui.imread(path);
final MatOfRect foundLocations = new MatOfRect();
final MatOfDouble foundWeights = new MatOfDouble();
final Size winStride = new Size(8, 8);
final Size padding = new Size(32, 32);

mHOGDescriptor.detectMultiScale(img, foundLocations, foundWeights, 0.0, winStride, padding, 1.05, 2.0, false);
Boolean withFace = false;
Rect[] array = foundLocations.toArray();
for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    Rect rect = array[j];
    Log.i("TEST", "Height " + rect.height + ", Width " + rect.width);
}
```

When I test it again a small set of 30 photos, I notice that the number of false positive is very high. Some of the photos with no obvious person features are flagged as with person too. (in the foundLocation array above and the rect height and width are quite high). For example, a photo with several flowers are flagged with 2 person inside. It's very obvious is wrong.

Is there anything I can do to improve it?

Comment: @pri - please don't use code markup for things that aren't code.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is Yes, there is.

If I understand correctly you have trained your descriptor on 30 photos? This is a very low number and by increasing your amount of training data would increase your detections.

---

Just in case you meant you were testing the same descriptor that you have used in your c++ code that worked then here is a slightly alternative answer.

Feature detection is a very difficult thing to master, even with a very good HOG detector it is likely that you will get many false positives. You don't mention how your true positive rate is doing, im going to assume its not too bad. Imagine how a flower looks to something that is trained to detect people, it is a long thin thing with a large circle at the top; pretty similar to a person...

Comment: Sorry that I am a very beginner in image recognition. I don't understand about the training of descriptor. I thought by calling "setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor.getDefaultPeopleDetector())" would set the correct detector that are already setup (trained) by OpenCV. Do we have to provide the training set ourselves? I refer to some of examples in C++ (e.g. peopledetection.cpp in OpenCV sdk), and I don't see they have to train their own descriptor. The 30 photos are actually my test cases. I run the code are 30 photos without person and most of them are wrong.

Comment: Btw, I also try to run the C++ example provided in OpenCV SDK, peopledetector.cpp, the result is very disappointing too. Some photos are obviously without a person, but it still highlights a corner of nothing as a person.

Comment: I'm not sure these comments have anything to do with the original question. You are asking about how well it should be working? the original question simply asked why you were getting error messages...

Comment: Huh? I didn't say I am getting error message in the original question. I meant I run the detectMultiScale() as per code above, getting a lot of regions detected as person, (foundLocations). When I marked those regions in the same photo and example the result, they are obviously wrong. i.e. Marking region with obviously no human as human detected.

Comment: My mistake, I got questions mixed up. Computer vision is not an easy task. Look up current results of other peoples HOG detectors and see if yours is similar